# Infinite scrolling grid and MVC

Tags: javascript, extjs

Let's say we follow an original article http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture and have such store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data/users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

And we decided to implement an infinite scrolling grid. To do that we need to remove `autoLoad: true` and invoke `store.guaranteeRange(...)` manually.

So what is the best place for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',
    autoLoad: true,
    remoteSort: true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/postdata/list',
        limitParam: 'size',
        startParam: undefined,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

Demo here http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-1-grid-infinite-scroll-in-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere where you render your grid. You can overwrite `afterRender()` method, or if it's modal grid/dialog - load the store before presenting it.

Couple side note (I'm trying to make a point that `autoLoad` usually is `false` for all stores:

- if you ever will use any authentication in your application - you
  will have to disable `autoLoad` on all stores.
- if you have more then couple stores (say 5-10+?) it's highly recommended to disable that too. You don't want all of them loading at the same time when application is starting.
- very often you need to have guarantee that something happened after the store is loaded and then again you disable `autoLoad`, subscribe to load event and `load()` the store manually.